# what is the naming convention around s_ in solidity

Tags: solidity, gas

I have seen staking balances using s_balances in contracts.

However, I tried searching around and I could not find the answers.

what is the naming convention around s_ in solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_` for "**s**torage".

The `s_` is a convention that seems to have been first adopted by the Chainlink developers ([example](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol#L29)) to indicate that a given variable is a storage variable, and therefore care should be taken in its use.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen in Patrick Collisions Videos, the `s_` is to notify developers that the computation on this data structure is gas-intensive.

For example

```
    // Account -> Token -> Amount
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256))
        public s_accountToTokenDeposits;
```

On such hashmaps, computations using them could be intensive, so devs would try to minimise changing the data in these datastructure.